# select onChange event triggers javascript that populates hidden Input value from an array value

Tags: javascript, html

I've done a ton of research over the net to come to this code failure :(  I have a select list that has an onchange event "emails()".  When a certain index value is chosen, I have the javascript pull an array value to populate the "recipient" INPUT value.  I know a little javascript, but not enough apparently.  Any help would be great, thanks in advance and I apologize if this post isn't "forum correct"  it's my first one :)

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function emails() {
var valObj = document.getElementsByName("recipient").value;
var selOpts = document.getElementsById("Concerning");
var selIndex = selOpts.selectedIndex;
var recValue = selOpts.options[selIndex].value;

var jvalObj =  new Array()
jvalObj[0]="Empty";
jvalObj[1]="email#1"; 
jvalObj[2]="email#2"; 
jvalObj[3]="email#3"; 
jvalObj[4]="email#4"; 
jvalObj[5]="email#5"; 
jvalObj[6]="email#6"; 
jvalObj[7]="email#7"; 
jvalObj[8]="email#8"; 
jvalObj[9]="email#9";

    for(i=0; i<selOpts.options.length; i++;)            
        if (recValue.value=="Benefits")
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[1].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value  = jvalObj[2].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value  = jvalObj[2].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value  = jvalObj[3].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[4].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[5].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value  = jvalObj[6].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[7].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[8].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[3].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[2].value; break;}

        if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true)
            {valObj.value = jvalObj[9].value; break;}
       }    
}</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/cgi-bin/formmail" method="post" >
    <td width=255 valign=top style='width:191.25pt;padding:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt'>
    <select onChange="javascript:emails();"
" id="Concerning">
                    <option value="">
            <option value="Benefits">Benefits
            <option value="Customer_Service">Customer Service
            <option value="Employee_Paperwork">Employee Paperwork
            <option value="Human_Resources"> Human Resources
            <option value="Open_Positions">Open Positions
            <option value="Payroll">Payroll
            <option value="Quote_Request">Quote Request
            <option value="Safety">Safety
            <option value="Technical_Support">Technical Support
            <option value="Training">Training
            <option value="Unemployment">Unemployment
            <option value="Workers_Compensation">Workers' Compensation
    </select>
    </td>

    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="recipient" VALUE="">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="subject" VALUE="Contact Form">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="postmaster@company.com">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="required" VALUE="Name,Phone,Email,Concerning,Comments">


  </form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: think you have a cut-n-paste error. document.getElementsById should be document.getElementById as it only gets a single element.

Comment: also you onChange should just be onChange="emails();" don't need to add "javascript:"

Answer (score 2):

Now that I finally get it, this should do the trick.

```
document.getElementById('Concerning').onchange = function() { 
    var myArray = ["Empty", 
                   "email#1", 
                   "email#2", 
                   "email#3", 
                   "email#4", 
                   "email#5", 
                   "email#6", 
                   "email#7", 
                   "email#8", 
                   "email#9"];

    document.getElementsByName('recipient')[0].value = myArray[this.selectedIndex];
};
```

Although I might do something like this instead because it is a lot shorter:

```
document.getElementsByName('recipient')[0].value = 'email#' + this.selectedIndex;
```

---

I think this is a whole lot simpler than you are making it. If I am interpreting your code correctly, all you want to do is take the selected value of the list and stick it into the hidden input `recipient`. In that case you can pass `this` to the onChange declaration. The new selected value will be the value of that list. Finally, get the hidden input and set the value there.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvvQd/

```
<select onChange="emails(this);" id="Concerning">
```

In this code the function `emails` accepts a single parameter. We pass `this` to that parameter which is the select list. You used `getElementsByName` incorrectly in your original code. This returns an array of elements with that name (as name isn't unique per page). So assuming there is only one we retrieve the zero index. You should probably give that field an id and retrieve it by that instead. Finally we just set the hidden fields value to the select list's value.

```
function emails(elem) {
    //you should probably give this an id and retrieve using that instead
    var recipients = document.getElementsByName('recipient')[0];
    recipients.value = elem.value;
}
```

Actually, if you wanted to make this super short you could do:

http://jsfiddle.net/pvvQd/1/

I would encourage you to stay away from inline javascript declarations. Instead you can do something like this. That way your code and html are not intertwined.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvvQd/2/

```
document.getElementById('Concerning').onchange = function() { 
    document.getElementsByName('recipient')[0].value = this.value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not what I'm looking for.  Based on what is chosen from the Select list, I'll pull the associated email from the array(jvalObj) to populate the hidden "recipient" field.  I know the javascript I can put right inside the onchange, but I'd rather not have the emails as the selection values.

Comment: @user1181400 - Ah, I see now. Sorry I missed that. See this - http://jsfiddle.net/pvvQd/3/

Comment: The first is what I want, I can just match the amount of values in the array to the select list.  So I'll have multiples of some email addresses.  Once I put in the actual email addresses, it wouldn't work. like None@none.com.  It dropped the quotes in the array in the site you gave me.

Comment: It's wierd once I changed the email#1 to actual email, it won't populate to the text field. Ex. "None@none.com"  I also added more array values, which I didn't think would make a difference.

Comment: @Kswizzle33 - Can you post a fiddle of the non-working example? I don't quite understand what is wrong. For example, this seems to work still - http://jsfiddle.net/pvvQd/12/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a cut-n-paste error. `document.getElementsById` should be `document.getElementById` as it only grabs a single element.

There is also an error with an extra `"` `<select onChange="javascript:emails();" " id="Concerning">` should be `<select onChange="javascript:emails();" id="Concerning">`

Also you `onChange` should just be `onChange="emails();"` don't need to add `"javascript:"`

Try changing inputs to have an ID value not just name that way instead of using document.getElementsByName (which returns an array and why your `valObj.value` assignment fails as it should be `valObj[0].value =` ) you can use `document.getElementById("recipient")`

You are also checking for the value of `recValue` here  `if (recValue.value=="Benefits")`
 when that variable is already the value so it should be `recValue == "Benefits"`.

You don't need to go through all of the element as you already have the selected index and could just act off of that single value. The loop is just overkill. Not certain what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: mrtsherman simplified it to an array and two lines of code for me :)  Yeah it looked a little over kill, more or less a collaboration of ideas I found.  Thanks for incite!

Answer (score 0):

Suggested edits to the original source code, see comments for edits.

```
function emails()
{
    var valObj = document.getElementsByName("recipient").value;
    var selOpts = document.getElementsById("Concerning");
    var selIndex = selOpts.selectedIndex;
    var recValue = selOpts.options[selIndex].value;

    /*Since the array will assing default integer indices where keys don't exist
      we can rewrite the array as follows to spare redundant write access to it*/
    var jvalObj =  new Array("Empty", "email#1", "email#2", "email#3", "email#4", 
                             "email#5", "email#6", "email#7", "email#8", "email#9");

    for(i=0; i<selOpts.options.length; i++){                        
            if (recValue.value=="Benefits"){
                    valObj.value = jvalObj[1].value;
                    i = selOpts.options.length;

            /*Each of the deleted conditionals used the same comparison which means 
              that they will never meet their criteria without first meeting this 
              conditional, which was set to break the loop*/
            }else if (selOpts.options[i].selected==true){
                    valObj.value  = jvalObj[i].value;

                    /*Personal preference: unless you're bound to the use of break I'd leave use i = len
                      - the exception being where you'd want to retain i of course
                    */
                    i = selOpts.options.length;
            }
    }
```

The html

```
<!-- DOM events carry out javascript callbacks by default -->
<select onChange="emails();" id="Concerning">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng"> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function emails()
{
    var recipient = document.getElementById("recipient");
    var concerning = document.getElementById("Concerning");

    var recipientEmailToSet = concerning.options[concerning.selectedIndex].value;

    recipient.value  = recipientEmailToSet; 

    //Remove next line for alert to go away
    alert(recipient.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/cgi-bin/formmail" method="post" >
    <td width=255 valign=top style='width:191.25pt;padding:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt'>
        <select onChange="emails();" id="Concerning">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="email#1">Benefits</option>
            <option value="email#2">Customer Service</option>
            <option value="email#3">Employee Paperwork</option>
            <option value="email#4"> Human Resources</option>
            <option value="email#5">Open Positions</option>
            <option value="email#6">Payroll</option>
            <option value="email#7">Quote Request</option>
            <option value="email#8">Safety</option>
            <option value="email#9">Technical Support</option>
            <option value="email#10">Training</option>
            <option value="email#11">Unemployment</option>
            <option value="email#12">Workers' Compensation</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <input TYPE="hidden" id="recipient" VALUE="" />
    <input TYPE="hidden" id="subject" VALUE="Contact Form" />
    <input TYPE="hidden" id="email" VALUE="postmaster@company.com" />
    <input TYPE="hidden" id="required" VALUE="Name,Phone,Email,Concerning,Comments" />


  </form>
</body>
</html>
```